# R equivalent to matlab griddata, scatteredInterpolant, and/or TriScatteredInterp

Tags: r, matlab

We do a lot of full field 3D numerical simulations (CFD, FEA, etc.). The solutions take a long time to run. We often interpolate from solutions rather than rerun every case. We also interpolate between multiple solutions, which leads to even higher dimensional interpolation (like adding time, so x,y,z,t,v).

Matlab does a great job of reading data V at irregular grid of X,Y,Z coordinates, and interpolating from V using griddata, scatterdInterpolan, and/or TriScatteredInterp. For a variety of reasons, I've switched to R. This remains one key area I've not been able to find as good R equivalent. 'akima' only does x,y,V (not, x,y,z,V, much less even higher dimensions like x,y,z,t,v).

The next best thing I've found has been 'krigging'. But krigging behaves more like model fitting and projection, and often does not behave well between irregular grid points. So it's not nearly as robust as simple direct linear interpolation.

Matlab has had griddata for several decades. It's hard to believe R doesn't have an equivalent out there. Any suggestions? Or is there at least a way to use krigging to yield effectively the same result as a direct linear interpolation?

Jonathan

Answer (score 2):

You might start by looking at the package "tripack" to do Delaunay triangulation, which gives you the first step in duplicating scatteredInterpolant().

Answer (score 0):

R `interpp()` is equivalent to MATLAB `scatteredInterpolant()`.